# How do I access latest state in useEffect (when updating state) without including dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, setstate

I'm trying to access the latest state in other setState function, cant figure out the correct way of doing it for a functional component

without accessing the latest state `setMoviesList`set state as undefined and causes issues

**state**

```js
  const [movies, setMoviesList] = useState();
  const [currentGenre, setcurrentGenre] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [genreList, setGenreList] = useState();
  const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(false);
  const [previousMovieList, setPreviousMovieList] = useState();
```

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getMovies(currentGenre, page) {
      if (currentGenre) {
        const data = await rawAxios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=f4872214e631fc876cb43e6e30b7e731&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}&with_genres=${currentGenre}`
        );

        setPreviousMovieList((previousMovieList) => {
          if (!previousMovieList) return [data.data];
          else {
            if (nextPage) {
              console.log(previousMovieList);
              setNextPage(false);
              return [...previousMovieList, data.data];
            }
          }
        });
        setMoviesList(previousMovieList.results);
      } else {
        const data = await rawAxios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=f4872214e631fc876cb43e6e30b7e731&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}`
        );

          if (!previousMovieList) {
            console.log('!previousMovieList', previousMovieList); 
            console.log('!data', data.data); 
            setPreviousMovieList(previousMovieList)
          } else {
            if (nextPage) {
              console.log('else', previousMovieList);
              setNextPage(false);
              setPreviousMovieList([...previousMovieList, data.data])
              
              // return [...previousMovieList, data.data];
            }
          }
        setMoviesList(previousMovieList.results);   
      }
    }
    getMovies(currentGenre, page);
  }, [currentGenre, page, setMoviesList, nextPage]);
```

*want to access latest `previousMovieList` here*

`setMoviesList(previousMovieList.results);`

Comment: Merge these two states (movies / previousMovieList) and then use setState with callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `previousMovieList` in your `useEffect` dependency array as follows:

```
useEffect(()=>
   {...}, 
   [currentGenre, page, setMoviesList, nextPage, previousMovieList]
);
```

Without including it, you will have a stale closure and latest value will not be reflected in your function. This is causing the initial `previousMovieList` value of `undefined` to never update within your useEffect logic.

If you dont want it in your `useEffect` deps, you can use a ref:

```
const previousMovieList = useRef();
//then in your useEffect
setMoviesList(previousMovieList.current.results)
//and to set it
previousMovieList.current = ... // whatever you want to store
```

Or you can do something like this:

```
    setPreviousMovieList((previousMovieList) => {
      if (!previousMovieList) return [data.data];
      else {
        if (nextPage) {
          setNextPage(false);
          return [...previousMovieList, data.data];
        }
      }
      setMoviesList(previousMovieList.results);
    });
```

Basically move `setMoviesList` to within the setPreviousMovieList function where you do have access to `previousMovieList`.

Kind of hard to tell what you're trying to do, but generally when you want to store the previous value of state, you would use the `ref` approach. Like [usePrevious](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/#:%7E:text=Hooks%20are%20a%20feature%20in,them%20in%20your%20next%20project.) for example

Comment: when I add `previousMovieList` in dep. array it causes infinite loop

Comment: Yep I can see why,  since you're also setting it in the useEffect. See my updated answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Add `previousMovieList` in `useEffect` dependency array, which allows react to know that its a dependency and reload when the dependency changes

Answer (score 0):

you can use optional chaining to access the data coming from the api

```
    enter code here
    const [movies, setMoviesList] = useState();
  const [currentGenre, setcurrentGenre] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [genreList, setGenreList] = useState();
  const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(false);
  const [previousMovieList, setPreviousMovieList] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getMovies(currentGenre, page) {
      if (currentGenre) {
        const data = await rawAxios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=f4872214e631fc876cb43e6e30b7e731&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}&with_genres=${currentGenre}`
        );

        setPreviousMovieList((previousMovieList) => {
          if (!previousMovieList) return [data?.data];
          else {
            if (nextPage) {
              console.log(previousMovieList);
              setNextPage(false);
              return [...previousMovieList, data?.data];
            }
          }
        });
        setMoviesList(previousMovieList?.results);
      } else {
        const data = await rawAxios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=f4872214e631fc876cb43e6e30b7e731&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=${page}`
        );

          if (!previousMovieList) {
            console.log('!previousMovieList', previousMovieList); 
            console.log('!data', data?.data); 
            setPreviousMovieList(previousMovieList)
          } else {
            if (nextPage) {
              console.log('else', previousMovieList);
              setNextPage(false);
              setPreviousMovieList([...previousMovieList, data?.data])
              
              // return [...previousMovieList, data?.data];
            }
          }
        setMoviesList(previousMovieList.results);   
      }
    }
    getMovies(currentGenre, page);
  }, [currentGenre, page, setMoviesList, nextPage]);
```

Comment: but how does this help me access latest `previousMovieList` in `setMoviesList(previousMovieList.results); `